# Not able to import SMOTENC

Tags: python-3.x, importerror, imblearn

I am able to import SMOTE from imblearn library but when importing SMOTENC it is throwing an error:

> 'ImportError: cannot import name 'SMOTENC''

I have tried changing the version of imblearn but no luck there

```
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTENC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try uninstalling and installing it again:

```
pip uninstall imblearn
pip install upgrade
pip install imblearn
```